# C# How to copy files from one directory to another without overwriting the files in the destinaton directory?

Tags: c#

This is how it looks so far, newbie here so, I would appreciate any tips or suggestions.

```
    private void btn_browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog open = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tb_path.Text = open.SelectedPath;
        }

    }

    private void btn_browse_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog open = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tb_dest.Text = open.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void btn_copy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(tb_dest.Text))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tb_dest.Text);
        }
        foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(tb_path.Text))
        {
            File.Copy(path, path.Replace(tb_path.Text, tb_dest.Text), true);
        }
    }
```

This curretly only copies files from one chosen directory to another chosen directory. When I copy the files to the destination directory, if there is by any chance a file named the same it overwrites it, and that's the problem.

Comment: Change File.Copy(path, path.Replace(tb_path.Text, tb_dest.Text), true); to File.Copy(path, path.Replace(tb_path.Text, tb_dest.Text), false);

Comment: So do you want to skip that file, stop copying all files or write the file with a new non-duplicate name?

Comment: I want to write the file with a new non-duplicate name